# JSch SSH connection throws NPE when initializing reverse tunnel

Tags: java, jsch, sshd

When I'm adding a reverse tunnel to a `com.jcraft.jsch.Session` object, the connection initialization fails with the following stacktrace:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session._setPortForwardingR(Session.java:2165)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.setPortForwardingR(Session.java:1937)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.setPortForwardingR(Session.java:1883)
        at com.project.client.handlers.SshClientHandler.<init>(SshClientHandler.java:41)
        at com.project.client.pcConnection.init(SdConnection.java:30)
        at Sdclient.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Packet.padding(Packet.java:58)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.encode(Session.java:892)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session._write(Session.java:1362)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.write(Session.java:1357)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session._setPortForwardingR(Session.java:2160)
        ... 5 more
```

The full code there is

```
private static JSch sshConn = null;
private Session sshSession;
public SshClientHandler(int _sshLocalSp, int _sshRemoteSp) {

    JSch.setLogger(new JSCHLogger());
     sshConn = new JSch();
    try {
        createTemporarySshFiles();

        sshConn.setKnownHosts(GeneralMethods.getPreference(PcPreferencesEnum.SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE));
        sshConn.addIdentity(GeneralMethods.getPreference(PcPreferencesEnum.SSHC_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE), GeneralMethods.getPreference(PcPreferencesEnum.SSHC_PUBLIC_KEY_FILE), "".getBytes());

        sshSession = sshConn.getSession(GeneralMethods.getPropValue("pcclient.id"), "sshserver.project.com", 22);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sshSession.setConfig(config);

        sshSession.setTimeout(15000);
        sshSession.setPassword("");
        //sshSession.setPortForwardingR("50000:localhost:22");
        sshSession.setPortForwardingR(50000, "127.0.0.1", 22);
        sshSession.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

The connection estabishes successfully w/ publickey authentication when I remove the line

```
sshSession.setPortForwardingR(50000, "127.0.0.1", 22);
```

The SSH user has the right to connect to the local port 50000 on the remote machine. Here is a snippet from it's `authorized_keys`

```
no-pty,permitopen="localhost:50000",command="/bin/echo not-allowed-to-do-this",no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAA[...]
```

I switched arguments for `setPortForwardingR` back and forth, as - for example - some documents I found online use the remote machine as second argument, some use localhost, but with no success.

Watching `auth.log` on the remote server indicates that the connection is not even initiated. The `NullPointerException` gets thrown on the actual line of the `setPortForwardingR` call. I ensured that my local SSH server is running on the local port 22, and I can connect manually to it. I tried different ports (to my local MySQL server, e.g.), but it always fails with the same stacktrace.

I'm using `jsch-0.1.52.jar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the [`.setPortForwardingR()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setPortForwardingR-int-java.lang.String-) only after the `.connect()`.

See for example:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Daemon.java.html

Comment: HOURS! I've spent HOURS on this issue! Thanks so much! :D

Comment: Check source code the next time. I do not know Java nor JSch, yet it took me one minute to find out.